# groovy 3.0.9 import static variable doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, static-import, groovy-eclipse

I have upgraded from groovy 2.4.10 to 3.0.9 and it broke the static variable imports. I am using groovy-eclipse-compiler. Here are some implementation and the error details (I have created a minimal repo that reproduces the behavior. here's the link: https://github.com/avdhut1222/demo):

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Groovy Plugins

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8-01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8-01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Source class

```
package com.srcpkg

class SrcClass {
   static SomeClass staticVar
}
```

Destination class

```
package com.destpkg

import static com.srcpkg.SrcClass.staticVar

class DestClass {
   method1 () {
      String str = staticVar.str1
   }
}
```

Error

```
ERROR in DestClass.groovy (at line 3)
    import static com.srcpkg.SrcClass.staticVar
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The field SrcClass.com.srcpkg.SrcClass.staticVar is not visible
```

The static imports used to work with groovy 2.4.10 and corresponding versions of groovy-eclipse-compiler. Any pointers what's the issue here?

Comment: What package is `SrcClass` in?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have provided sample implementation here. But in actual implementation SrcClass is in different package than the DestClass

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior.  If you can share a simple sample project that demonstrates the problem, I am certain the fix will be a simple one.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have created a minimal repo that reproduces the behavior. here's the link: https://github.com/avdhut1222/demo

Comment: I see now.  It looks like you are using `groovy-eclipse-compiler` and I overlooked that in the original question.  I don't know what is wrong and my comment about it being a simple fix didn't take that compiler into account.  The project compiles if you remove that, but I can't help with the Groovy Eclipse compiler.  Best of luck!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown do you think using gmaven (plus) might help in this case?

Comment: I do not know. I don't have experience with gmaven.

Comment: I tried replacing it with gmavenplus but doesn't help. Thank you for looking into it @JeffScottBrown

Comment: isn't `package` the reserved key-word?

Comment: @injecteer this is just sample pseudo code. of course the actual name of package is not package. check the github link for dummy implementation details

Comment: Your import is for a static field which is private. If you change staticVar to getStaticVar in the import, you can still reference the property with staticVar in method1.

Comment: Or you can add public modifier to staticVar and it will become an accessible field.

Comment: @emilles let me try that. I assumed the default access modifier in groovy is public

Comment: @emilles yes the static import for getStaticVar works. Need not even had to change the staticVar usage. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @emilles for the answer (above comments). Posting the updated code here for destination class

```
package com.destpkg

import static com.srcpkg.SrcClass.getStaticVar

class DestClass {
   method1 () {
      String str = staticVar.str1
   }
}
```